# Registering users with PHP, HTML input?

Tags: php, html, input

I have this file here:

```
<?php 
    include 'core/init.php';
    include 'includes/overall/header.php';

    if(empty($_POST) === false){
        $required_fields = array('username','password','password_again','first_name','email');
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
            if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true){
                $errors[] = 'Fields Marked with an asterisk are required';
                break 1;
            }
        }   

        if(empty($errors) === true){
            $args = $_POST;
            if(user_exists($args['username'])){
                $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \''.$args['username'].'\' is already in use.';
            }else if(preg_match("/\\s/",$args['username']) == true){
                $errors[] = 'Your username can not contain any spaces.';
            }
            if(strlen($args['password']) < 6){
                $errors[] = "Your Password is to short! It must be at least 6 characters. If you want to know why you need to use a better password visit this page, <a href=\"http://howsecureismypassword.net/\">password checker</a>.<br/>";
            }else if($args['password'] !== $args['password_again']){
                $errors[] = "Your passwords do not match!";
            }
            if(filter_var($args['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
                $errors[] = "A valid email address is required.";
            } else if(email_exists($args['email']) === true){
                $errors[] = 'Sorry, the email \''.$args['email'].'\' is already in use.';
            }
        }

    }


?>
<h1>Register</h1>
<?php 
    if(empty($_POST) === true){
        include 'includes/register.php'; 
    }else if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
        //Register user
        echo "Registered User";
    }else{
        echo output_errors($errors);
        include 'includes/register.php'; 
    }?>
<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php';?>
```

Heres register.php:

```
<?php
    $username = "";
    $first_name = "";
    $last_name = "";
    $email = "";
    if(empty($_POST) === false){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <ul>
        <li>Username*: <br/><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>"/></li>
        <li>Password*: <br/><input type="text" name="password"/></li>
        <li>Confirm Password*: <br/><input type="text" name="password_again"/></li>
        <li>First name*: <br/><input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>"/></li>
        <li>Last name: <br/><input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>"/></li>
        <li>Email*: <br/><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"/></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Register"/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

This isn't ever going to be a real site, it's just me playing around with PHP, what I realised is that when a user submits their data they can put in what ever they want, so if they put in some HTML, would it render as well? like... would they be able to put in the input field `last_name` a value like `"<p>blah blah blah</p>"`, would this essentially render as

Last name: 
blah blah blah

""/>

Because wouldn't that be kinda bad for the site? They could break it or something?

So is there something that fixes this? Like replaces tags like `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` and makes `"` into `\"` or escapes these characters?

Also... is there anything terribly wrong with my code?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php does it

Comment: If you put that in an answer...

Comment: Yes. It's called an Cross site scripting attack (XSS or CSS). What's worse is if people input javascript to steal cookies or do other nefarious things with the browser. For something like this you can use `htmlentities` to convert any HTML, rendering it harmless. Or if you want some HTML to be available you can use an HTML parser to parse out everything except allowed tags.

Comment: I think you should put that as an answer so I can accept that. That is what I was thinking could happen >.<

Comment: A couple things:  a) although it's not "wrong", there's no reason to write `if(empty($_POST) === false)`; `if(!empty($_POST))` is the same thing when the argument to `empty()` is an array.  b) Same for `in_array()` (don't need the `===`).  c) You've got the _opposite_ problem with `if(empty($value))` on line 8. It's not a good idea to use `empty()` on a string, since it returns `true` for the string `'0'`. Use `if(!isset($value) || $value == null)` or something like it instead. (Often I just use `if($value == null)`, since it's usually good enough.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, I figured that you could do that, but I just left it like that while I was still developing it, more so I could change the value easily, can you use `!` in front of a boolean in php?

Comment: Yep, just like in Perl and other similar languages. Also, PHP is kind of weird in that you sometimes _need_ to use `===` (as with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)), but most of the time it's not necessary. It is (slightly) faster though, and some people advocate using it all the time for consistency.

Comment: I usually use `==` when im not sure if it's going to return a boolean type, but I use `===` when I know its going to return a boolean type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

**htmlentities**

> This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except
>   with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity
>   equivalents are translated into these entities.

Answer (score 1):

you may use either [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).